# error al implementar barra de busqueda en app nodejs y angular

Tags: nodejs, api, mongodb, express, peticiones

Buenas amigos tengo una app con mean stack de tipo red social algo asi, en la que los usuarios pueden hacer publicaciones, enviar mensajes, seguirse entre si, etc. el problema es que quiero implementar una barra de busqueda para buscar publicaciones por su titulo el backend esta funcionando perfecto, ya que lo testeo con postman y me devuelve las publicaciones que quiero por su titulo pero no logro conectar con frontend en angular, me devuelve conjunto vacio al enviar la palabra que quiero buscar.

BACKEND

```
BACKEND

function getFilterPublications(req, res){
    var matches = req.body.word;

    Publication.find({title: matches }).exec((err, publication) => {

        if(err) return res.status(404).send({message: 'error en la peticion'});

        if(!publication) return res.status(500).send({message: 'No hay publicaciones con ese titulo'});
        
        if(publication) return res.status(200).send({publication, matches});


    });
}

SERVICIO DE ANGULAR

    getFilterPublications():Observable<any>{
        let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json')

        return this._http.get(this.url+'filterpub/', {headers: headers});
    }
COMPONENTE

    onSubmit(form){
        this._publicationService.getFilterPublications().subscribe(
            response => {
                if(this.publication){
                    this.status = 'success';
                    form.reset();
                }else{
                    this.status = 'error';
                }
            },
            error => {
                console.log(<any>error);
            }
        );
    }

FORMULARIO

      <form #searchForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(searchForm)" class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input name="word" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar Canje">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Buscar</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: No veo que estés enviando el cuerpo (`body`) en la solicitud `http`. Cuando usas una llamada tipo `GET` debes adjuntar el cuerpo de la solicitud de forma explícita, en cambio cuando usas una llamada tipo `POST` el cuerpo se adjunta por defecto a partir del contenido del formulario. Tienes 2 opciones: adjuntas la información del formulario explícitamente en tu llamada `GET` o cambias la llamada por una de tipo `POST`. Saludos

Comment: En conclusión deberia de adjuntar el body en el return del servicio, o cambiar a post toda la peticion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No estas enviando tu búsqueda.

```js
onSubmit(form) {
  this._publicationService.getFilterPublications(form.value.word).subscribe(
    response => { 

      //Revisa la estructura que recibes desde el backend
      console.log(response)
      if (this.publication) {
        this.status = 'success';
        form.reset();
      } else {
        this.status = 'error';
      }
    },
    error => {
      console.log( < any > error);
    }
  );
}
```

2. Cambia tu servicio a post para que coincida con tu backend.

```js
getFilterPublications(word: string): Observable < any > {
  let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  //Enviamos el body
  return this._http.post(this.url + 'filterpub/', {
    word
  }, {
    headers: headers
  });
}
```

3. Asegúrate que tu backend este recibiendo en `post`.

## Edición

Cambia la estructura de tu formulario a esta:

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(busqueda.value)" class="navbar-form navbar-left">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input
      #busqueda
      name="word"
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Buscar Canje"
    />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Buscar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Y corrige en tu component.ts:

```js
onSubmit(busqeuda) {
  this._publicationService.getFilterPublications(busqueda).subscribe(
    response => { 

      //Revisa la estructura que recibes desde el backend
      console.log(response)
      if (this.publication) {
        this.status = 'success';
        form.reset();
      } else {
        this.status = 'error';
      }
    },
    error => {
      console.log( < any > error);
    }
  );
}
```

Fue mi error. Asumí que estabas usando reactive forms. Lo que estoy haciendo es llamar directamente el valor del input con `#busqueda.value`

Comment: hola, hice tus correciones y me devuelve el array de publications vacio aun, nose sinceramente donde puede estar el error el backend va perfecto con post y get es problema unicamente de front el que estoy teniendo

Comment: Dentro del subscribe te puse un console.log, que aparece?

Comment: ese console log me devuelve esto {
  "publication": []
}

Comment: y por backend me devuelve esto {
    "publication": [
        {
            "_id": "6181e3c846ded53e50e8b363",
            "created_at": "1635902408",
            "user": "616e273fc65b811c38b1aa74",
            "file": "wzjXYqp7vMkjLzW0m0FhTrTh.jpg",
            "type": "iphone se",
            "title": "iphone 6",
            "text": "tengo iphone 6 sin uso casi anda correcto",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Pon un console.log en tu backend y haz una petición desde postman, y otra desde angular. Debería en ambos mostrar el resultado, si no es asi, has un console.log(req.body) para ver si estas recibiendo el parametro por post. Si lo estas haciendo por get, cambia la cosa.

Comment: el console.log desde postman me devuelve esto [Object: null prototype] { word: 'iphone 6' }, y si hago la peticion desde angular me devuelve { } todo por metodo post, creo que el problema es que nunca llega el valor al body desde el input de mi formulario pero nose como solucionarlo

Comment: te actualizo, he sustituido el `this._publicationService.getFilterPublications(form.value.word)` por un JSON directamente `({word: "iphone 6"})` y efectivamente me devolvio la publicacion, entonces el problema esta entre el formulario y el component.ts no?

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta. @FacundoSuarez

Comment: excelente efectivamente me funciono!, agradezco mucho tu ayuda mil gracias!